# Enable Inspector v2 with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-inspector

is it possible to enable Inspector new version by Terraform? as in https://registry.terraform.io/, I only found inspector classic resources

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Comment: @Marcin: enable Inspector 2 in a multiple-account with local-exec is complicated since Terraform not supported. If I want to update delegated administrator account or disable inspector2 for all account, I have to implement script to do that.

Comment: Yes, you have to design everything from zero as TF does not support inspector 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its **not supported**, but there is already [github issue for that](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22330). In the meantime you can use `local-exec` with AWS CLI or `external data source` to work with `inspector2`.

Comment: if using local-exec with AWS CLI, I cannot disable inspector2 when I run terraform destroy, isn't it?

Comment: @TienDungTran No sure at the moment.

Comment: It was released in v4.37.0 of the Terraform AWS Provider.